# Calculation returns after second press on button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I'm new to Objective C. I'm experiencing issues whilst creating a unit conversion app. Here is the offending code (P.S I'm aware that isn't the correct conversion):

The problem is that when I press the convert button, it returns with the initialisation value of 0. I then have to press the button again to get my calculated value. Thank you.

Of course I'm a hugeee noob, this is my first day :).

```
-(IBAction)convert:(id)sender{

int unitType;
double unitTemp1 = [_tempField.text doubleValue];
double unitTemp2 = 0;

switch(unitType)
{
    case 1:
        //Celcius to Farenheight
        NSLog(@"Celcius to Farenheight Selected");
        unitTemp2 = unitTemp1*9;
    break;
}

if([_array objectAtIndex:1])
{
    unitType = 1;
}


NSString* resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",unitTemp2];
_tempResult.text = resultString;
//initwithformat
}
```

Comment: When this method executes, unitType is not initialised, and can be any random value. So no telling how your switch() statement will behave, Always initialise your variables in Obj C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you set `unitType` after the switch, solution is to move the code above, and provide a default to your switch

```
int unitType = 0;

if([_array objectAtIndex:1])
{
    unitType = 1;
}


switch(unitType)
{
    case 1:
        //Celcius to Farenheight
        NSLog(@"Celcius to Farenheight Selected");
        unitTemp2 = unitTemp1*9;
    break;
    default:
        //match anything else
        NSLog(@"Celcius to Farenheight not Selected");
    break;

}
```

Comment: Way to edit your code after I put my answer @meda -- at least give me an upvote since you stole my thunder

Comment: @PanoKatsourakis bro why would you accuse me of stealing your answer, they are not even the same. the concept of this community is to help out, not be a rep-whhore

Comment: We answered at almost the same time. Yours was way less detailed at that point. I left then you edited your answer so that it would be more likely to be chosen as correct. Who is the rep-hore here??

Comment: well I am not the one begging for upvote, I posted before you and while I was editing you come make the same point and then complain smh.

Comment: @PanoKatsourakis Meda's "answered Aug 1 '14 at 15:48" - Yours "answered Aug 1 '14 at 15:50" - it's clear that his was 2 minutes earlier. A lot of water can go under the bridge in 2 minutes ;-) Timestamps do not lie.

Comment: lol @Fred-ii- exactly bro, crazy things happen on this site haha

Comment: @meda - and crazier things will continue to happen - *Cheers* ;-) I hope you are well bro.

Comment: lol je suis un man, j'espere que toi aussi je t'ai appeler bro a quelque reprise now, ok removing them now :P

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your if statement up so it is initialized to a value before your switch statement

```
int unitType;

if([_array objectAtIndex:1])
{
    unitType = 1;
} else
{ 
    unitType = 0;
}
```